# GCM Notification -google project related query

Tags: android, push-notification

I'm working on the **GCM notification** functionality so I created a project in the google and used the project_id and server_key using my personal email account.Its working fine but now I want to do same functionality for another gmail account with same package name.Is it possible ?
Example :

```
Created 
 project A in google 
 project Id : 121223233434 
(abc@gmail.com)
 Package name for App com.abc


Now Same functionality for:
project B
Project_id : 131313131313
(pqr@gmail.com) 
Package name for App com.abc
```

Is it working or not?
I aleready created such functionality but not working ,If any solution then please suggest me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I just want to do the GCM functionalty on the another gmail account instead my account. PLease any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put the two JSON file in single app folder so you have to work with only single id for all the features of google provided push notification, firebase,google login...etc

Comment: Ok then I have to delete the project that created in my account then and then it works for another account...right.?

Comment: you also can change in your existing project with newly provided json file paste in app folder and change the app key

Comment: I just login from the other device and use the registration id of that device it works for me. Thank you